# Dockerized Laravel App, always 404 on assets

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

So, after a lot of trying i managed to get my Laravel 5.6 app to run via docker. I am creating the image and storing it on Amazon ECR. Then via docker-compose i am loading the Laravel, Nginx and some others.

Everything works perfectly except for one thing. Everything related to assets like css and js are not loaded (404).

I tried loading them with '/' in front, i tried via the assets() function, to no avail.

So, here are the files i have used:

Dockerfile of Laravel app:

```
FROM php:7.1.15-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
mysql-client zip unzip git libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng12-dev libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
&& pecl install imagick \
&& docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd mcrypt pdo_mysql \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY php-fpm.conf /etc/php-fpm.conf

COPY www.conf /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY . /var/www

RUN composer update

RUN chown -R www-data: /var/www
```

This image is built fine and stored in Amazon.

The docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:

  # The Laravel Application
  app:
    image: URL_TO_IMAGE-WORKS
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./storage/app:/var/www/storage/app
      - ./storage/logs:/var/www/storage/logs
      - "./php-fpm.conf:/etc/php-fpm.conf"
      - "./www.conf:/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf"
    links:
    - database
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

#The Nginx server
  proxy:
    build: server
    working_dir: /var/www
    restart: always
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    volumes:
      - ./mysqldata_2:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=secret"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_USER=secret"
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - database
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306

  elk:
    image: sebp/elk
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
      - "9200:9200"
      - "5044:5044"
```

The NGINX Docker file is:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
COPY proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

The proxy.conf used by NGINX:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  admin.mydomain.com;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    index index.php server.php;
           root /var/www/public;

           location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
           }

           location ~ \.php$ {
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
               fastcgi_pass app:9000;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               include fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
           }

   }
```

So, after everything starts up nicely, and i navigate to the admin.mydomain.com functionality wise its ok, but neither css nor js files load.

I tried a lot of different settings, both on the docker image and the nginx settings to no avail. Any insights would be highly appreciated!

Note: should you need any extra infos, please let me know

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm stuck on the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not...

Comment: I'm receiving 404 *locally* when I try to run packages like log-viewer and debugbar. If I run with php artisan serve everything works fine.

Comment: Log into your 'app' image and see if the assets are there. You don't have your local source directory mapped to your container directory

Comment: @UnderDog all sources are copied in the image. And i have confirmed it by browsing the app container...

Comment: @JimBantanis-Kapirnas did you solve this ? I have same issue...

Comment: @Dulo I never managed to get it working, so i abandoned it. I switched it to Apache and works like a charm. There is definitely a way to do that, I mean, most installations use Nginx.. i just was not able to do it..

Comment: I' also having this problem. Surely theres a way to get it working with nginx since a lot of other apps do this too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

- I linked the storage (`php artisan storage:link`) locally, and made sure I could locate the files through `ls` while in the container.
- I made sure my vhost.conf (using apache) was following symlinks.
- I checked the at mod_rewrite was enabled (`a2enmod rewrite`) at the end of the dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx (proxy docker) serve directly the static content without use php script (app docker).
The docker-compose file must define the volume parameter for proxy service :

```
 proxy:
     build: server
     working_dir: /var/www
     restart: always
     # Here the volume defined
     volumes:
       - ./:/var/www
     ports:
       - "80:80"
```

complete working without DB :

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www:cached
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    ports:
      - 81:81
```

app.dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.1.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
```

web.dockerfile :

```
FROM nginx:1.10
ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

vhost.conf :

```
server {

    listen 81;
    index index.php server.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, will try it out soon and let you know, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and solved it by mapping the public folder of my laravel container to the nginx container with the help of this SO question: [docker-compose: how to map a file from a container into a volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864573/docker-compose-how-to-map-a-file-from-a-container-into-a-volume)