# docker-compose: how to map a file from a container into a volume

Tags: docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to share a file from one container to another other. An essential detail is that (the machine running) my docker host does **not** have explicit access to the file: It pulls a git repo and doesn't know about the internal file organization of the repo (with the single exception of the docker-compose file). Hence, the approach of standard mapping `<host-path>:<container-path>` is not applicable; e.g. this is not possible for me: [How to mount a single file in a volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248198)

Below is the *docker-compose* file, stripped for increased readability. Say `service_1` has the file `/app/awesome.txt`. We then want to mount it into `service_2` as `/opt/awesome.txt`.

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:

    service_1:
        volumes:
            - shared_vol:/public
            # how to make service_1 map 'awesome.txt' into /public ?

    service_2:
        volumes:
            - shared_vol/awesome.txt:/opt/awesome.txt

volumes:
    shared_vol:
```

Working solutions that I have, but are not fond of,

- running a script/cmd within `service_1`, copying the file into the shared volume: causes race-condition as `service_2` needs the file upon startup
- introducing a third service, which the other two `depends_on`, and does nothing but put the file in the shared volume

Any help, tips or guidance is most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you just do something like this

```
version: '3.5'

volumes:
   xxx:

services:

   service_1:
      ...
      volumes:
         - xxx:/app

   service_2:
      ...
      volumes:
         - xxx:/opt
```

Comment: If I can, I will feel extremly stupid: I thought the making of a volume (this way) would overwrite everything within `service_1`'s */app* and `service_2`'s */opt* ... but I will test it regardless and come back: thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It is absolutely ridiculous how many hours I've spent on this ****, and the proper way to do it was such a trivial approach.. I don't know why I thought the docker host would overwrite anything in the (shared) volume, but  obviously it doesn't... Well thank you good sir, you made my week!